# ¿Cómo redondear a un decimal valores agregados en un input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quisiera que al ingresar los valores en el input se redondeen automáticamente (cambiando ahí mismo en el input)

```
Entrada
5,25
5,15
salida
5,3
5,2
```

```html
<input type="number" id="madera" name="madera"
       min="10" max="100">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) para ello. Y si quieres mostrarlo en el input entonces puedes usar el evento `change` que se activa cuando el valor ha sido modificado (o cuando pierda el foco). Si usas el evento `input` o `keyup` da problemas mientras escribes al agregar automáticamente los decimales establecidos en **toFixed()**.

```js
madera.addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log(parseFloat(madera.value).toFixed(1))
  this.value = parseFloat(madera.value).toFixed(1)
})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="madera" name="madera"
       min="10" max="100">
```

Comment: agradezco tu rta, sólo que no lo modifica dentro del mismo input, debería forzar automáticamente el cambio dentro del mismo input. Ej si ingresa 5.25 que cambie ahí mismo el valor a 5.3

Comment: Acabo de modificar mi respuesta, no se si te vale así.

Comment: eres un genio!!!!